# PHP session error: “File too large”

Tags: php, session

I have a php web site. While browsing my site, sometimes home page displays a warning message see below

> Warning: session_start()
>   [function.session-start]:
>   open(/data/tmp/sess_cf04f579f3929206a5af1b25e0bb6fd0,
>   O_RDWR) failed: File too large (27) in
>   /htdocs/index.php on line 1

I don't know what is this?

I have started the

```
<?
session_start( );
?>
```

we have set only some values in Session( store 10 variables). Is it a problem . if it so what is the maximum number of session variables

Comment: What are you saving in your sessions?  If you're saving large, complex objects, this might cause problems along the lines of those you've described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> File too large

sounds like you are storing *huge* amounts of data in sessions - so much, in fact, that the file system can't deal with them any more (which would hint at sizes beyond 2 or 4 GB!)

You would have to look at the data you are storing, and find a different way of storing it.

Another reason for this could be that the `tmp` directory has reached a quota of some sort. That would fall into the server administrator's department to fix.

> **Update:** Seeing as another user asked the very same question a minute ago, this could also be some kind of server problem at a very large provider.... In that case, contact that provider.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid saving large amounts of information in the session data; if you have large objects, offload them to a database of some sort.