# Error message about session_start() and "File too large"

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP session error: “File too large”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741197/php-session-error-file-too-large)

Hello,

Out of the blue I got the error below on my index page.  Line two has `session_start();`.  Any idea what could have caused the error below?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/data/tmp/sess_cec...fd, O_RDWR) failed: File too large (27) in /data/15/2/161/14/.../user/.../htdocs/index.php on line 2
```

Comment: Wow... same question was asked about a minute ago. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3741197

Comment: Are you sure there is enough disk space?

Comment: Seeing as there are answers on the older question already, closing as duplicate.

Comment: If you @John are not identical with that other user, this is starting to sound like a server problem with a major hosting provider

Comment: @Pekka, no, I'm not the same person.  I'm using shared hosting with Network Solutions, a large American hosting provider.  Any ideas what I should do?  I don't think I'm storing a large amount of data in sessions at all.

Comment: @John if you're not storing huge amounts of data in the session (see that other question) then you're probably not at fault and you need to speak to their tech support

Comment: Thanks, Pekka.  I hope that this is a temporary issue that Network Solutions will be able to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about huge data in session, may be there is some problem in your code , which may be appending same data again and again. Which finally lead to fail.

try changing session path ie instead of tmp

```
session_save_path('/home/example.com/sessions')
```

Comment: see the discussion in the comments, this seems to be a server problem